# Redmine in subfolder. Drupal (in main folder) handles all requests

Tags: drupal, redmine

I have Redmine in subfolder /var/www/redmine and Drupal in folder /var/www/

When I go to URL mysite.com/redmine, Redmine shows ok, but mysite.com/redmine/login is (over)handled by Drupal.

Apache config is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
        RailsBaseURI /zoo-redmine

        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as `RewriteRule ^zoo-redmine - [L]` before other rewrites in .htaccess

This code exits .htaccess file if encounters zoo-redmine string and don't allow Drupal to readdress this request to index.php with arguments

Answer (score 1):

It seems a Drupal configuration issue. Try to look in your Drupal configuration panel to exclude from Drupal's login system the /redmine/ subfolder. I can't point you to the exact url because my drupal configuration uses CAS, but it is probably in

```
Start -> Administration -> Configuration -> People
```